# Java: What is the equivalent of != when comparing strings?

Tags: java, string, boolean

I would like the while loop to execute whenever the user enters a value other than "stop" or "continue" when ignoring case. How can I do this?  Whenever I run the program it prints "Invalid entry" even if I type in continue or stop. What am I doing wrong?

```
package butt;

    import java.util.*; // used for console input

    public class butt_face{

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); // needed for user input

    public static void main(String[] args) {

   String strContinue; // input from console and used for boolean

    System.out.println("Would you like to stop or continue? ");
    strContinue = console.next();
    while(!(strContinue.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) || !(strContinue.equalsIgnoreCase("continue")))
        {   
            System.out.println("Invalid entry");
            System.out.println("Would you like to stop or continue? ");
            strContinue = console.next();
        } // end while
    if(strContinue.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")
    {
        System.out.println("Good bye!");
    } // end if
    else
        System.out.println("Poop Ship Destroyer");

    } // end of main

    } // end of class
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: More specific?  He wrote the code for you.  Look at it and think.

Comment: `if(!someString.equals(otherString))`

Comment: @ duffymo !str.equals() does not ignore case

Comment: You should check out some tutorials on formal logic to help out with your control statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the wrong operator:

```
!(strContinue.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
```

is `true` unless `strContinue` is `"stop"`.

```
!(strContinue.equalsIgnoreCase("continue"))
```

is `true` unless `strContinue` is `"continue"`.

`strContinue` cannot be both `"stop"` and `"continue"`, therefore at least one of the conditions will always be `true`, and `false || true` is `true`.

**Solution**: change the or (`||`) to an and (`&&`).

Comment: @Boognish If you found this answer useful, feel free to upvote and accept it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace with a && in the condition instead of ||
Check the repl https://repl.it/B6GJ/0

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your logic.

```
  while(!(strContinue.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) || !   (strContinue.equalsIgnoreCase("continue")))
```

This part checks if strContinue is equal to stop if it is equal to stop it will then check to see strContinue is equal to continue.

Answer (score -5):

Do something like a input function that calls the input scanner until you entered one of these two strings.

Comment: Why would you call functions to simply compare two strings?

Comment: I dont get his point really as he used a special variation of equals and keeps asking for the general one! So I just wanted to recommend him to outsource his code into a input method that keeps running until the wished result so he can re use it anywhere.

Comment: Well his (i.e. the OP's) "point" is ill-founded, really.  But >>the real point<< is that he has made a basic logic mistake in his code.  Your answer says nothing to address either issue.